# Target the right class

Tags: jquery, api, vimeo, flexslider

I try to deal with Vimeo API and flexslider callback function.
Each slide of my gallery is a video. 
The problem is : turn ON/OFF the video when we move to a new slide.

The current slide have a ".flex-active-slide" class that I try to target but I can't achieve this. I think my problem is due to $f(iframe).

But I can see how I can solve that

```
var iframe = $('#vimeoplayer')[0];
            var player = $f(iframe);
            $('.flexslider')
            .fitVids()
            .flexslider({
                animation: "fade",
                slideshow: false,
                animationSpeed: 300,
                controlNav: 'thumbnails',
                directionNav: false,
                before: function(slider){
                    $('.flex-active-slide').find('player').api('pause').api('unload');
                },
                after: function(slider){
                    $('.flex-active-slide').find('player').api('play');
                }
            });
```

Any help is welcome ! 
Thanks

Comment: specific reason to use `$f(iframe);` check the `$f` alias. and you can share the errors if you do have in browser console. have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

As i can guess you have an alias `$f` for `jQuery` and it seems that you have not defined it anywhere, so there might be an error which might break the code at that line and other code will not get executed:

```
var iframe = $('#vimeoplayer')[0];
var player = $f(iframe); // here might be error like "$f is not defined"
```

As you are using `$` alias so better to stick with it, change to this:

```
var iframe = $('#vimeoplayer')[0];
var player = $(iframe);
```

Comment: The $f is specific to the Vimeo API call Froogaloop https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#universal-with-froogaloop

Comment: I've got an error in the JS Console : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b') line 25 on the Vimeo file : https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js